# SQL with dynamic exclusion, condensed into one query (SQLite)

Tags: sqlite, select

I have two tables:
Table1: id1, field1, field2, field3
Table2: id2, field1, field3

What I need is:

```
"select id2 from table2 where field1 = x and field3 = y;"
```

if it returns empty then perform and process the results from:

```
"select field2 from table1 where field1 = x and field3 = y;"
```

Is there a way to perform this in a single query in SQLite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the tables are joinable on `field1` and `field3`, then something like this should work (Warning:  Untested):

```
select
  case when sum(count_id2)>0 then a.id2
  else b.field2 end as column
from(
  select id2,count(1) as count_id2
  from table2
  where field1=x and field3=y
  group by id2
)a
join(
  select id2,field2
  from table1
  join table2
  using(field1,field3)
  where field1=x and field3=y
)b
using(id2);
```